# How to solve : The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.3.10 and higher.?

Tags: gradle, flutter, gradle-kotlin-dsl

i have tried so many diffrent solutions on stack / git , none of them worked so far ..

So the problem is when i'm trying to build my apk  on release mode ofc  , they shoot me with a problem which is basically about some compatibility i  guess  .

```
* What went wrong:

The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.3.10 and higher.

The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:

root project 'android' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.71
```

this problem only showed up after installing this package : [folder_file_saver](https://pub.dev/packages/folder_file_saver)

Any help would be appreciated .

ps: I ran **flutter pub get**  .. and **pub upgrade**  .. everything went well ..

Well flutter is not upgraded to the last version , i like that current version more .

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. The solution that worked for me was reopening the project and ignoring the Plugin Update Recommendation at the bottom right of the screen.

Once I stopped the clicking update, the error went away.